Can you safely use a magnetic switch with LED strips?
Magnetic switches I've found have very low current ratings, like 0.5A. Typical LED strips draw up to 4A. These two seem to be incompatible, yet I see people connecting magnetic switches to LED strips. Am I missing something?

That's what relays are for. Or you can use a amplifier for the same thing, the amplifiertakes a -12V signal and delivers -12V power to the LEDs when that signal is on. An amplifier does that 3-4 times for R G B W.  So run -12V through the magnetic switch to the input on the amplifier and Bob's your uncle.

People do thing without looking at compatibility and are then surprised when things start failing.
You can sidestep the current issue by using a relay of some description to switch the actual current and the magnetic switch then only sees the coil current of the relay, which tends to be in the milliAmp range.

there's no good reason to use a relay over virtually any N-channel MOSFET, and a lot of reasons the FET is better (silent, lasts forever, no wasted coil current, smaller, etc). Splice the FET into the LED- line in front of the PSU (Source=PSU Neg, Drain=LED Neg), then feed 12v to the Gate from the magnetic switch and you're done. Use virtually any TO-220 MOSFET, ex; IRFZ44N.

@dandavis that would be a solid state relay, which is included in "relay of some description"

fair nuff, I tend to avoid that term because most SSRs are for AC. DC SSRs do accept a higher trigger voltage (usually 30-40v) compared to a FET (vgs:15-20v) and can be placed source or sink, features which aren't needed here, but add to the cost.
